# changing specific letters in a string

Tags: python

```
from random import randint
tal = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
sign = ['@','£','$','€','&', '!', '?', '!']
bogstaver = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
             'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z']



numbers = [tal[randint(0,9)] + sign[randint(0,7)] + bogstaver[randint(0,24)] + tal[randint(0,9)] for x in range(4)]
password = "".join(numbers)
print(password[2::8])

print(password)
```

I want every 4., starting from the second first letter in a password to uppercase the letter in the string. 
Which is the [2::8] of the code. But I just cant figure out how to only replace these two letters with the same letter in uppercase.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
password = ''.join([c.upper()
                    if i in range(2, len(password), 8)
                    else c
                    for i, c in enumerate(password)])
```

Comment: @sebastian you understand `join` and list comprehensions so I'm not sure what needs explaining. What don't you understand?

Comment: @sebastian have you googled what enumerate does and how to use it?

Comment: yeah, its not enumerate, its more what "i" stand for in this comprehension list which I doesnt understand.

Comment: @sebastian it's for the index in the string, which I need to say `if i in range`. Try `print(list(enumerate(password)))` to see what you get.